# Google Map - ajax update icons

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, google-maps-api-3

I have a script that plots the latlng on a map, once the map is drawn my script them performs ajax request to get the icons in the hope of  updating the map with new marker icons.

This is what i have so far:

```
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost/new/cqc/get_rating.php',
    data: 'location_id=<?php echo $row['location_id']; ?>',
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        icons=[response];
    }
});


    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
        scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(10,10),
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        title: markers[i][0],
        icon: icons[i][0]
    });
```

This doesnt work, the icons do not appear.

Kind regards

Comment: Yes, call marker inside success in ajax call.

Comment: please could you elaborate further

Comment: Sorry, remove 'var' keyword for icon variable.

Comment: nope - no luck there

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. You just have to fix the **positioning** of your codes.

Here's how I made it work:

First, I made sure all necessary variables are declared. I have provided the array content for `markers` so I could use it after loading the `map`. Then I added the array `icons` for later use, and the `map` variable to handle the map class.

```
var icons = [];
var markers = [
  ['Chicago', 41.878114,-87.629798],
  ['Detroit', 42.331427,-83.045754],
  ['Kansas', 39.099727,-94.578567],
  ['Des Moines', 41.600545,-93.609106],
  ['Colorado Springs', 38.833882,-104.821363],
  ['Nashville', 36.162664,-86.781602],
  ['Indianapolis', 39.768403,-86.158068],
  ['Lexington', 38.040584,-84.503716],
];
```

Next, I initiated the map: (this example centered on Chicago)

```
function initMap() {
  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latlng.lat, latlng.lng)
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 41.878114, lng: -87.629798},
    zoom: 5
  });
```

The map must be showing up now on the page. After that, we will be running the `ajax` call that you have made to populate the `icons` array. (*I'm not really sure if your `ajax` code works because I have no way of testing it*).

```
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'http://localhost/new/cqc/get_rating.php',
       data: 'location_id=<?php echo $row["location_id"]; ?>',
       async: false,
       success:function(response){
         icons=[response];
       }
    });
```

The return from your `ajax` code must look something like this to make your code work:

```
[
  ['icon1.png'],
  ['icon2.png'],
  ['icon3.png'],
  ['icon4.png'],
  ['icon5.png'],
  ['icon6.png'],
  ['icon7.png'],
  ['icon8.png']
];
```

After getting the `icon` array populated, you may now proceed with the loop. Inside your loop, must be the variable that will contain your `icon` and the function for creating marker (*in this code, I have separated the marker function*):

```
  for( var i=0; i < markers.length; i++){
    var image = {
      url: icons[i][0],
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 32)
    };
    create_marker({lat:markers[i][1],lng:markers[i][2]}, i, image);
  }
}
```

You may see in the above code that the `scaledSize` is inside the variable `image` which will serve as your `icon` object (compared to your's which is inside the `marker` variable). This is because, the `scaledSize` is for the icon itself and not for the marker.

Now, outside the `function initMap`, we will add the `function create_marker`. Take note of the variables passed in the parameters of the function, which is the `position`, the `i` variable to get the number of loop, and the `image` to add the icon:

```
function create_marker(position, i, image){
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: markers[i][0],
    icon: image
  });
}
```

This should now work! Check this [sample](http://jsbin.com/riwoqef/edit?html,js,output) to see the codes in action. (*Don't forget to read the comments to get a better understanding of what I did!*)